# Why pgRouting GUI panel may not work in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, pgrouting

What could be the reason behind the mal-functionality of the pgRouting Layer GUI panel?

In order to route shortest path via dijkstra function code I'm able to conduct the task using the following code:

`SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost, geom
  FROM pgr_dijkstra(
    'SELECT id, source, target, st_length(geom) as cost FROM schema.cvl',
    1, 100, false, false
  ) as di
  JOIN schema.cvl pt
  ON di.id2 = pt.id ;`

but unable to do the same using the pgRouting Layer GUI panel!

> An error has occured while executing Python code: .............

I searched for this error on the net and found out that it may happen because the database password is not saved.. So, I saved the password, but still getting same error when I try to locate source_id or target_id on the map

I'm using QGIS 2.0.1 and pgRouting pg93-binaries-2.0.0

Comment: Please post the actual error text.

Comment: What was message error? If it was this message "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'db' referenced before assignment"
You need to change the name of connection to postgres for the same name of Database.